# Make div expand to table size

Tags: html, css

So I have this

```
<div class="table-container">
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <table class="sometable"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The table is larger than table-wrapper or table-container. How do I make either of the two parents expand to cover the table?

Thanks

Comment: Uh, are there any CSS styles already associated with these elements? Those could be handy to have when trying to answer a (presumably) CSS-related question. Also, your `<table>` probably shouldn't be self-closing; perhaps it should be rewritten as `<table class="sometable"></table>`?

Comment: hmm, tried `height:auto`?

Answer (score 1):

fix width of outer div and give table `width:100%;`... It might work :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have explicitly set the width or height of the container divs, they will expand to fit the size of the table naturally. This will not necessarily be the case if the position of your table is set to absolute - in that case, use position relative on the table instead to avoid this problem as absolutely positioned elements do not go with the natural flow of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSS doesn't look like this:

```
.sometable {
   position: absolute;
}
```

If you are using `position: absoulute;` then you need to change it to `position: relative;` or totally remove it.

try using `width:100%` maybe that will help.